# Laravel 5.2 Query Builder get as a single array(not 2D or 3D)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

This is my query.

```
$mem = DB::table('user_zakathorg')
       ->JOIN('zakathorgs', 'user_zakathorg.zakathorg_id', '=', 'zakathorgs.ID')
       ->WHERE('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id )
       ->SELECT('zakathorg_id', 'orgName')->get();
```

And the output is always one raw. like following image

[image]

If i want to accesss the **zakathorg_id**. I have to use a foreach loop. And I can't access

`$mem[0]['zakathorg_id]`

how can i use this as simply `$mem['zakathorg_id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `first()` method instead of `get()`:

```
$mem = DB::table('user_zakathorg')
       ->JOIN('zakathorgs', 'user_zakathorg.zakathorg_id', '=', 'zakathorgs.ID')
       ->WHERE('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id )
       ->SELECT('zakathorg_id', 'orgName')->get();
// You can access $mem->zakathorg_id now
```